# getAbsolutePath() NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm working on a Halo: CE custom game launcher in Java, and I'm setting up a preferences system using the Properties class in Java, so the user can set custom game paths. I use a JFileChooser to select a file and then write that path to the config file.

But, the program gives a Null Pointer Exception at this line: (This is in the event listener function)

```
if(source == fovChooseButton)
    {
        int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(settingsWindow);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File selected = chooseFOV.getSelectedFile();

            try
            {
                config.setProperty("STLPath", selected.getAbsolutePath()); //This line gives the exception
                config.store(new FileOutputStream(CONFIG_FILE), null);


            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                handleException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I do have another JFileChooser, and it does not throw any exceptions. Here's the code for the other one:

```
    if(source == fileChooseButton)
    {
        int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(settingsWindow);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File selected = chooseFile.getSelectedFile();

            try
            {
                config.setProperty("GamePath", selected.getAbsolutePath());

                config.store(new FileOutputStream(CONFIG_FILE), null);

            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                handleException(e);
            }
        } // end if

    }
```

All handleException() does is display a dialog window with the stack trace.

Help?

Comment: Have you checked if config may be null?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and linenumbers?

Comment: So which object is null - is it `config`, or `selected` - have you printed them out to check?

Comment: Are you certain that `chooseFOV` has a selected file?  That is the cause of your NPE.

Comment: Well, I would guess it is `File selected = chooseFOV.getSelectedFile();` that returns null - have you checked that the file you are trying to get actually exists?

Answer (score 3):

Your prompting the User for a file with *chooseFile* afterwards you are trying to read the file from the other filechooser chooseFOV

```
int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(settingsWindow);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File selected = chooseFOV.getSelectedFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

> int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(settingsWindow);
>      File selected = chooseFOV.getSelectedFile();

You have two variables and probably want to use `chooseFile` on the second line as well.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that in the event listener for     chooseFOV opened the dialog for     chooseFile.

Answer (score 0):

What's chooseFOV ? You seem to be using chooseFile for the dialog, so it's the one that's got a selection.